# Someone who knows he is too small to change politics, but still wants to fight

Tags: single-word-requests, politics

What is the word for someone who wants to fight against corruption in politics, but he knows he's too small to really change anything?

For example many artists are like this:

What do you call an artist who does his best to fight against politics even though knows everything is ruined beyond repair?

Comment: "Fighting against politics" sounds a little like taking up arms against war.

Comment: I'm reminded of the Mother Teresa quote: "If you can't feed a hundred people, feed just one." (Even if you know your change won't amount to much, keep doing what you can.)

Comment: @TusharRaj: Agreed. Sure, it will be only 1 person, but that's still 1 person who will be infinitely greatful they can eat for today. That's a beautiful thing in itself.

Comment: Should the "but" in the title really be "even though" - your question text suggests you want a word for someone who knows they are destined for failure, but tries anyway; the title sounds like someone who is giving up.

Comment: Should be called a **futilist**.

Answer (score 7):

I think the artist you are referring to can be described as a ***[Don Quixote](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Don+Quixote)***:

> - An impractical idealist bent on righting incorrigible wrongs.
>     (After Don Quixote, hero of a satirical chivalric romance by Miguel de Cervantes.)

***Quixotic***:

> - Caught up in the romance of noble deeds and the pursuit of unreachable goals; idealistic without regard to practicality.

(AHD)

Comment: Nice answer. Should maybe add the word 'quixotic', though?

Comment: Does quixotic imply that they _know_ they're too small to change anything?

Comment: @TusharRaj - it may,  an impractical idealistic would not be stopped by that.

Comment: @Josh61: They wouldn't be stopped, but that's not the point. IMO, quixotic implies _think they can_, as opposed to _know they can't_. See the Mother Teresa quote in my comment above. I wouldn't call that kind of thinking quixotic.

Comment: @TusharRaj - I didn't say it is. We are just referring to two different issues.  I think OP is looking for the one I am suggesting. Post your own answer if you have a different view.

Comment: @Josh61: I will if I think of something that fits. The self-awareness part is an important requirement of the OP which `quixotic` lacks, IMO. Just pointing that out. Peace.

Comment: @TusharRaj - the difference would be that Mother Teresa wasn't waging war on the Machines. Maybe the Don's agenda wasn't so impractical, misguided, or deluded, after all. Have you watched Mr. Robot? It's an uninterrupted progression from them damned windmills to the rise of the Machines! ;-)

Comment: Remember that this character was crazy

Comment: This doesn't describe someone who 'knows he's too small for that and he can't change anything'.

Answer (score 3):

*[Pragmatic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pragmatic)* describes the willingness to do something in spite of the disappointing expectations:

> adjective
>
> 1 Dealing with things sensibly and realistically in a way that is
>   based on practical rather than theoretical considerations:
>   *a pragmatic approach to politics*
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

*[Cynic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cynic)* describes that sense of hopelessness:

> 1.1 A person who questions whether something will happen or whether it is worthwhile:
>   *the cynics were silenced when the factory opened*
>   <sub>*ODO*</sub>

Should this person be called a *cynic* or a *pragmatist*? It is hard to choose between the two, but since this is a single word request, *pragmatic* seems to embrace the notion of cynicism sufficiently. *Pragmatists* understand the limits of a situation and simply do what they can to make the most of it.

Together, the two words make a great team. For his noble efforts to keep the ethnic tinderbox of Europe at peace in the early 20th century, the statesman [Klemens von Metternich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klemens_von_Metternich) was honored by Arnold Blumberg with the label of *[pragmatic cynic](https://books.google.com/books?id=nofUu5tvJ18C&pg=PA197&dq=pragmatic%20cynic&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UT-bVfvTBYva-QHkxIvgCA&ved=0CEIQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=pragmatic%20cynic&f=false)*:

> The splintering of Central Europe, and the creation of so many
>   nonviable states since the war, may give us renewed respect for the
>   *pragmatic cynic* whose name is forever associated with the years
>   1815-1848.
>   <sub>*Great Leaders, Great Tyrants?: Contemporary Views of World Rulers who Made History*</sub>

As Plato is [said to have said](https://books.google.com/books?id=77QmKama9qgC&q=%22The%20penalty%20good%20men%20pay%20for%20indifference%22%20Plato&dq=%22The%20penalty%20good%20men%20pay%20for%20indifference%22%20Plato&hl=en&sa=X&ei=olmbVZbQK4Xe-QHIuoLQBg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwATgK):

> The penalty good men pay for indifference to public affairs is to be
>   ruled by evil men.
>   <sub>*Congressional Record, Volume 98, Part 6, Page 7944*</sub>

[John Stuart Mill](https://books.google.com/books?id=xs5BAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA62&dq=pacify%20%22good%20men%20should%20look%20on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R1ibVfj3DMa5-AGWl4DQDg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=pacify%20%22good%20men%20should%20look%20on%22&f=false) concurred:

> Let not any one pacify his conscience by the delusion that he can do
>   no harm if he takes no part, and forms no opinion. Bad men need
>   nothing more to compass their ends, than that good men should look on
>   and do nothing.
>   <sub>*Rectorial Address Delivered at the University of St. Andrews*</sub>

Comment: I would say someone willing to spearhead a  campaign that has little hope of success (*disappointing expectations*) is an *idealist*, not a pragmatist.  A pragmatist and a cynic would know *fighting* against the big guns is a waste of time, effort and money. And I have never heard of a *cynic* being described as a person who experiences "hopelessness". The dictionary definitions do not match your unique take on their meanings.

Comment: Interesting dichotomy, @Mari-LouA. Would you say you're more an *idealist* or a *pragmatist*? I myself am a *pragmatic idealist*--the synthesis of a pragmatist and an idealist. We know how things ought to be, and we are willing to make strategic sacrifices to move in that direction even if we cannot effect perfection. May I suggest that the **sense** of *hopelessness* I noticed in the OP is modulated from *despair* to *cynicism* by the intense desire to do something? Human **emotions** are often the composite of polar opposites battling internally, but our **actions** define us.

Comment: A  *cynic* is but another word for a *pessimist*, and in my experience, neither are rarely self-starters, or self-motivated to initiate a battle knowing they will lose: **but he knows he's too small to really change anything**. Unless you have faith, and a conviction you are right, regardless of the opposition; you will never fight.

Comment: Is the answer now "*good man*"? Some pragmatists are very self-serving, and I'm not sure I would call a cynic a "good" person.

Comment: I'm not sure why you press *spearheading campaigns* or *self-starting* upon the discussion, @Mari-LouA, but pessimism and pragmatism are not mutually exclusive. The [Brooklyn Nets](http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/04/16/bkn-magic-nets-writethru-idUSMTZEB4GVOKN3V20150416) finished their **loosing** season with 38 wins and 44 losses, but clinched a playoff birth in their last game of the season. Players were as ***cynical*** as the fans about their chance at a championship, but being ***pragmatists***, they played three home playoff games in front of a full house :-)

Comment: @Mari-LouA, The apple of pragmatism is not being compared with the onion of altruism, nor the walnut of cynicism with the groundnut of virtue. Apples and walnuts are ingredients in a [Waldorf salad](http://www.knorr.ie/recipes/detail/9121/1/waldorf-salad), onion and peanuts are ingredients in [Kung Pao chicken](http://savoringtoday.com/2011/06/20/kung-pao-chicken-with-gluten-free-options-and-monthly-cooking-instructions/). Enjoy the Waldorf salad :-)

Comment: Tasty metaphor, @ShinyPenny!

Answer (score 1):

*[Political Underdog](https://www.google.com/search?q=political%20underdog&oq=political%20underdog)* may best represent someone who knows they have little chance of winning yet takes on the challenge with a glimmer of hope rather than delusion. There are numerous articles using this term covering individuals to minority parties.

Answer (score 1):

There are several phrases that I might give, but few single words. I hope that one of them might suit the needs of the OP.

If someone is showing dogged, naive determination in the face of political opposition, he might be referred to *Mr. Smith*, from the movie, [Mr. Smith Goes to Washington](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031679/). In this 1939 Frank Capra movie, the title character played by Jimmie Stewart fights political corruption because of his conviction and personality. (However, I think current audiences would more readily go to a character in *The Matrix*.)

A word for such a fighter might be *naive*.

If someone is showing noble determination but is unaware of the true nature of the political opposition, he might be referred to as *Quixotic*, as mentioned by Josh61. The task that the person is involved in may be called [Tilting at Windmills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilting_at_windmills).

The task that someone is engaged in might be called a [fool's errand](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+fool%27s+errand) which the Free dictionary calls

> an attempt to do something that has no chance of success

A single word for this might be *foolhardy*.

Someone who is fighting against a faceless bureaucracy and failing may be told, [You can't fight city hall](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/can%27t+fight+City+Hall).

Comment: Lol +1 for foolhardy. Nice out of the box thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

A person who is not allowed to vote is **disenfranchised**.

The term has broadened in meaning to refer to those who do not have a realistic voice / influence in say society. People who vote for a party which ends up with 12.6% of the votes but 0.15% of the seats in Parliament are disenfranchised in this broader sense.

> *disenfranchise* verb
>
> To disenfranchise is defined as to take away someone's right to vote
>   or to deprive someone of power, rights and privileges.
>
> When certain segments of the population are deprived of their right to
>   vote or of a position of power in society, this is an example of a
>   time when you disenfranchise that segment of society.

{[YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/disenfranchise)}

Comment: disenfranchised doesn't capture the subject's will to fight

Answer (score 0):

I think **grassroots** might capture what you're looking for.

A grassroots movement or organisation is one that is organised from 'the ground up' rather than being dictated to from the top down, as would be the case for a traditional organisation with formal hierachical power structures.

Examples

> My skating buddies and I organised a grassroots resistance against the council's anti-skating bylaws. At nighttime we went around putting up posters urging people to resist the by laws.
>
> The Potplant Liberation Front was a grassroots organisation. Its members were mostly part time volunteers who offered their time in the weekends.
>
> The party was organised in a very grassroots manner. Steve brought his sound system along, Joe had some spare tables in his garage, and Sue was always up for showing off her baking skills.

Good examples of real world grassroots organisations would be the [Animal Liberation Front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Liberation_Front) (who conduct criminal activity, and so by necessity do not have a centralised power structure) or [Food Not Bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_Not_Bombs), who tends to organise locally at a city by city level.